# My "JSON" isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm loading a large number of items on a page through JSON, but it isn't working. This is my first time using JSON and I figured JSON was just a big object so I copied my object that I had before in a variable into a file and names it fun.js.

You can check out the JSON here:

http://justpaste.it/15zc

I'm using jQuery to get the JSON:

```
$.getJSON('fun.js', function(data){
alert(data)
});
```

Nothing is being alert, in the matter of fact...the alert isn't happening at all. Anyone know why?

Comment: No. And I checked the network and I get an OK. And I even check for errors in the JSON, and I fixed all.

Comment: Are you familiar with FireBug? If you use `console.log(data)` in place of `alert()` does any data show up in the Console Log?

Comment: What if you try with smaller json like `{ foo: 'bar' }` at first?

Comment: I can just use the Chrome dev. But ill try.

Comment: This does not appear to be valid json. Try using the [json validator](http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: Start with a smaller JSON object. Something like `'{"foo":"bar"}'`. This will make it easier to tell if it's a JSON problem, or a fetching problem.

Comment: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ might shed some light

Comment: You shouldn't write your own JSON to begin with.  You should use a serialization utility on the server side.

Comment: Can you use \ in json? like `{"foo":"This is cool \"!\" "}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, your JSON doesnt validate. Go paste it here and fix your errors: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Secondly, user [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to which you can pass onError parameter so you'll get a warning that JSON didn't go through.

Comment: We can also just watch the network requests with something like Chrome's developer tools rather than hack in our own on-error callback exclusively for debugging.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know you need to use double quotes on everything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated that the JSON is the issue?  Open up Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools and refresh the page.  You may see a message that the file wasn't found or there was a parsing exception or a security error.

- If the file isn't found, you can fix that in the code.
- If there is a parsing error, use a JSON validator.
- If there is a security issue, see my answer to [Get a JSON file from URL and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456862/get-a-json-file-from-url-and-display/11456989#11456989).  You need to update your server policy or configure your browser to allow access to file URL's in your tests through.