# Convert JSON File to JSON Object

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON file like below and I want to desterilize it to JSON Object how can I do it ? Thanks

`{
  "TOTAL": 2,
  "PRODUCTS": [
    {
      "CODE": "T55",
       "PRICE": 59.95,
      "DESCRIPTION": "Ok"
       },
    {
      "CODE": "T75",
       "PRICE": 99.95,
      "DESCRIPTION": "Not OK"
    }]`

Comment: Did you write any code for this So far ? Did you try expiring newtonsoft.json library and how to use it? Did you try using the default json serialization classes available in .net?

Comment: Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249454/how-do-deserialize-this-json-into-an-object) to see an example to deserialize JSON into an object.

Comment: I use var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ? = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Library>(content);               I am not sure about ? part.

Comment: the content is like this "{\"TOTAL\":177,\"PRODUCTS\":[{\"CODE\":\"T55-2A\",\"PRICE\":59.9500,\"NAME\":\"Arrive In Style\"},{\"CODE\":\"F1-231\",\"PRICE\":49.9500      and it is ok

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link for parsing from a file :
[Get a JSON file from URL and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456862/get-a-json-file-from-url-and-display)

**And**

You can use :
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"Pawan", "age":24}');

Comment: This question is about C#, not JS.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers support JSON.parse().

```
var json = [{
"TOTAL": 2,
 "PRODUCTS": [
{
  "CODE": "T55",
   "PRICE": 59.95,
  "DESCRIPTION": "Ok"
   },
{
  "CODE": "T75",
   "PRICE": 99.95,
  "DESCRIPTION": "Not OK"
}];

var arr_from_json = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

In browsers that don't, you can include the json2 library.